# autowiring with a specific application.properties

Tags: java, spring

I want to use an interface with multiple implementations and a lot of different application.properties. If the active application-a.properties he should autowire the implementation a otherwise b.
So I got an interface like this:

```
public interface ab {
void dosomething();
}
```

and the classes:

```
public a() implements ab{
@Override
void do something(){
    System.out.println("Hello here is a");
}
```

```
public b() implements ab{
@Override
void do something(){
    System.out.println("Hello here is b");
}
```

I know there is the @Profile() notation, but is there something like @Profile(!"a")?

Comment: Yes, there is: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html *If a given profile is prefixed with the NOT operator (!), the annotated component will be registered if the profile is not active — for example, given @Profile({"p1", "!p2"}), registration will occur if profile 'p1' is active or if profile 'p2' is not active.*

Comment: You coud also have a look at [Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) annotation but profiles seem a better choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**but is there something like @Profile(!"a")?** [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

> If a given profile is prefixed with the NOT operator (!), the annotated component will be registered if the profile is not active — for example, given @Profile({"p1", "!p2"}), registration will occur if profile 'p1' is active or if profile 'p2' is not active.